# ANOVA problem: discrete distribution as response variable is possible?

Tags: correlation, anova

I have some questions concerning the ANOVA techniques assumptions:

1) If i have some treatments to test but these were not selected on the basis of a design of experiment method but randomly can they however be tested in some way?

2) If the response variable isn't a continuous variable the ANOVA is still valid? (i don't think so) Because I have a response variable expresses in a 1-7 discrete scale and the final aim of the analysis is to understand the impact of each factor on this response.  How can I do?

Comment: Can you tell us more about yout response variable? It is ordinal? It is a likert scale? What does it measure?